# Call a method only once after 1 second from a method which get called 2-3 times

Tags: java, android, android-webview

The below method `onReceivedTitle`gets called 2-3 times with in a second when `webview` url changes. I want to call a method in it, when `onReceivedTitle` is being called last time. I am doing this because I just want to monitor url changes with in webview. `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is not getting called when url changes through ajax.

```
class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {


        @Override
        public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
            Log.v("onReceivedTitle", "=>" + title);

            // callAMehod();
            super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);
        }

    }
```

Comment: How you will understand whether this is the last call or not?

Comment: Whenever the method get called first time after 1 or 2 second it will be the last time for sure. So basically I want to use something like timer.

Comment: Can you use Thread.sleep(6 * 1000); i.e. 1 second and try?

Comment: You mean put Thread.spleep in `onReceivedTitle` and `callAMehod();` after that?

Comment: then `callAmethod` will be called 2 or 3 times but I want to call it only once!

Comment: That you can easily stop by a static counter, no. If the value of the static counter is more than 1, just don't do anything inside the method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and do something like this:

```
class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    private boolean mOnReceivedTitleInvoked;

    @Override
    public synchronized void onReceivedTitle(final WebView view, final String title) {
        if (!mOnReceivedTitleInvoked) {
            mOnReceivedTitleInvoked = true;
            Log.v("onReceivedTitle", "=>" + title);

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);
                    mOnReceivedTitleInvoked = false;
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

}
```

Although you might want to reconsider the `onReceivedTitle` behaviour.

Comment: Hi @curtisLoew Can you tell me how can I reset the `mOnReceivedTitleInvoked` to false after my method getCalled once? If I press a url again then `mOnReceivedTitleInvoked` will be true and it will not let my method to run.

Comment: Please see my edit. Alternatively, see zapl solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to throttle how often a method call causes another method call you can do so for example via a `Handler`. The simplest version enqueues a delayed message on the first call and any subsequent call while there is an enqueued message will not enqueue a new one. That results in 1 call every X time to go though - but it take at least that amount of time until the first action happens.

Example implementation (you can put that class unmodified somewhere in your code)

```
public abstract class ThrottleExecutor {
    private final long mMinDelay;

    public ThrottleExecutor(long minDelay) {
        mMinDelay = minDelay;
    }

    /** Implement to do something */
    public abstract void doThrottled();

    public final void scheduleExecution() {
        if (mHandler.hasMessages(0)) {
            // message already enqueued, do nothing
        } else {
            // otherwise enqueue a message for later
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, mMinDelay);
        }
    }

    public final void cancelExecution() {
        mHandler.removeMessages(0);
    }

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            doThrottled();
        }
    };
}
```

And then use it for example like so

```
class Usage {
    private ThrottleExecutor mThrottle = new ThrottleExecutor(2000) {
        @Override
        public void doThrottled() {
            // happens at most every 2000ms
            methodToBeThrottled();
        }
    };

    void methodThatHappensTooOften() {
        mThrottle.scheduleExecution();
    }

    void methodToBeThrottled() {
        Log.d("TAG", "triggered at 2000ms before");
    }
}
```